# Compute ${\rm tr}(a_k a_{k'}\rho)$ with $\rho=e^{-\beta H}/Z(\beta)$ Gibbs state and $a_k$ ladder operators

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix

Consider a harmonic oscillator with hamiltonian $H=\sum_k\omega_k a_k^\dagger a_k$ and a state $\rho=\frac{e^{-\beta H}}{Z(\beta)}$ where $Z(\beta)=\text{tr}[{e^{-\beta H}}]$.
The quantity $$A:=\sum_{kk'}\text{tr}[a_ka_{k'}\rho] $$ should be zero; how can I see it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the route to take to get the answer: Assuming that the number operators commute, we can expand $$e^{-\beta H}=e^{-\beta\omega_1 a_1^\dagger a_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e^{-\beta\omega_N a_N^\dagger a_N}.$$ Now, we can represent a number operator as
$$n=\sum_m m|m\rangle\langle m|,$$ so $$e^{-\beta\omega a^\dagger a}=\sum_m e^{-\beta\omega m}|m\rangle\langle m|.$$ The total exponential then become
$$e^{-\beta H}=\sum_m e^{-\beta\sum_k\omega_k m_k}|m_1\rangle_1\langle m_1|\otimes |m_2\rangle_2\langle m_2|\otimes\cdots\otimes |m_N\rangle_N\langle m_N|.$$ In other words, the state $\rho$ has probability
$$p(m_1,\cdots,m_N)=e^{-\beta\sum_k\omega_k m_k}/Z$$ of being in the pure state $$|m_1\rangle\otimes\cdots\otimes |m_N\rangle.$$ It should be straightforward for you to evaluate the expectation values using linearity to show the desired property.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces spanned by the different ladder operators commute, so the problem is reduced to showing the desired property for a Hamiltonian of the form $H=a^\dagger a$ for some ladder operator $a$ (this can be $a_k$ for any $k$). You then remember that $a^\dagger a$ is diagonal in the number basis, and thus $f(a^\dagger a)$ is also diagonal in the same basis, for any sufficiently nice function $f$ (such as the exponential).

Thus the matter boils down to considering an operator $\sigma$ that is diagonal in the number basis, $\sigma=\sum_n c_n |n\rangle\!\langle n|$. Then, $\operatorname{Tr}(a \,\sigma)=0$ follows immediately, and similarly when you consider more than one annihilation operator in the trace.